# Checkbox count in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, checkbox

I have created this checkbox:

```html
<input v-model="compared" type="checkbox" name="compare" value="compare">
```

And I want to create a function to control this. In the function I want to
limit the number of selected boxes to 3 and arrange it to redirect to another page when it reaches 3. Is there anyone who can help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

```html
<template>
      <div>
        <div v-for="(item) in checkboxOptions" :key="item.value">
          <input
            v-model="checked"
            :id="item.name"
            :disabled="!checked.includes(item.value) && disabled"
            type="checkbox"
            :value="item.value"
            @change.prevent="checkHandler()"
          />
          <label :for="item.name">{{ item.name }}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      name: "App",
      data() {
        return {
          disabled: false,
          checked: [],
          checkboxOptions: [
            {
              name: "1",
              value: "1",
            },
            {
              name: "2",
              value: "2",
            },
            {
              name: "3",
              value: "3",
            },
            {
              name: "4",
              value: "4",
            },
          ],
        };
      },
      methods: {
        checkHandler() {
          if (this.checked.length === 3) {
            this.disabled = true

            // Perform what ever you want to do here
          } else {
            this.disabled = false
          }
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

Ignore the loop for now

v-model will add all the checked items in array. the change event will be called every time when change happens in input. This will check for the checked items if the checked items are 3 it will disable all the checkboxes so that no new item could be selected but you still can deselect already checked item. Inside the if you can redirect to another page.